# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, postman

``I am trying to implement token authentication in my Django Rest Framework application. I am able to receive a token from the django server but when I send a request with 'Authorization' header, I receive the following error:

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}

I have also checked the request.META and there is no key with name "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION". I am running my django app on development server.

**Views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view,authentication_classes,permission_classes
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required,login_required
import google.cloud.storage
import uuid
import psycopg2


@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def auth_test(request):
    return Response("it's great to have you here with token auth!!")

@api_view(['GET'])
def free_test(request):
    #print(request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
    return Response("entry without token auth !!")
```

What is the reason that my authorization credentials are not received by django server?

POSTMAN SCREENSHOT WHERE I HAVE PASSED THE AUTHORIZATION HEADER

[image: screenshot]

Comment: POSTMAN screenshot seems fine, anyway can you add your respective `view`?

Comment: I've added the views.py where am just catering a simple get request to see if token authentication is working, which is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access your view using `Token` auth method, and you are not mentioned that in `authentication_classes`. Try the following code

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def auth_test(request):
    return Response("it's great to have you here with token auth!!")
```